# What is the music genre of this part of this song?

Tags: identify-this-genre, similar-artists

At first I tried Moombathon, but that didn't come close and I tried future bass. I had the same result and not much progress. Maybe someone can help me out here.

Go here: https://youtu.be/OHgvreVW9PE?t=2m32s and skip to 2:34, listen to the song till 2:48! I would like to know what genre of music this part of this song here is. I like it a lot, and would like to find more similar kind of music. Thank you for reading, and listening at least :).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're talking about the drums and bass, because that's really the only part that's different in that particular segment of the song.

Those are Jamaican dancehall drums.  [Dancehall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancehall) is a [pop, dance-oriented derivative of Jamaican reggae](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-av7F1JBmj4) that has been popular since the late 1970s.  Introduced into the American pop mainstream by early 2000s star [Sean Paul](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MmW_GOFS8I), dancehall percussion is now a foundational part of the modern pop sound, contributing stylistically to recent hits by artists such as [Justin Bieber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRh_vgS2dFE).

I haven't heard it combined with Asian music styles before, but I found [this J-Pop Dancehall compilation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b08TYaHVmqQ) with many songs similar to your reference song.  There's also apparently a popular Japanese dancehall artist named Akane who has a song out called [Rude Gyal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDCLkJbAgZ8).

Comment: Thanks for this mah dude its the closest i've gotten to it still not 100% but atleast i know a genre that comes closest.

Answer (score 1):

That fragment is a broken beat interlude of a hard-dance track. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAB4fA-tDpw) is similar music, though not always as hard as your fragment. The tracks are labeled as Kawaii Pop, Future Bass, Hard-Dance, EDM and J-Pop.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into Happy Hardcore, there's tons of samples of Jungle, DnB and breakbeat. Classic Happy Hardcore is from the mid 90s but you might discover this sort of beat(s) you are looking for while starting here... the hardcore style might be a style you should research. Enjoy raving!

https://www.mixcloud.com/martin-green3/off-yer-nut-99-spaced-out-dj-fury-mix-trance-core/